# taps issue with heroku db:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, taps

first of all, I'm using RVM... and I don't know much about managing gem lists.

So, I tried to push my db to heroku using heroku db:push, and I get the following error:

```
$ sudo heroku db:push
Taps Load Error: no such file to load -- taps/operation
You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
On most systems this will be:

sudo gem install taps
```

I installed taps (sudo gem install taps, now at taps 0.3.23), and I have the latest heroku. No idea why this is happening ... and I can't seem to find much info on it online either. I tried running sudo heroku db:push, but that didn't change anything at all.

I also tried to install the gem locally (?) but that gave me a gem permission error.

Any ideas on what could be happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using RVM, you should never use sudo.

Which ruby do you have RVM set to use at the time when the push is failing? You should just need the heroku and taps gems install for that ruby (again, no sudo). Use "gem list heroku" and "gem list taps" to check.

Comment: I see, interesting. So what should I do now? I tried to do gem install taps ... but that gave me a gems permission error.

Also, here's another bit of info (thanks so much for your response!):
`$ gem list heroku

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

$ gem list taps

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

taps (0.3.23)`

Answer (score 11):

If your using RVM, then

```
gem install taps
```

if your not, then

```
sudo gem install taps
```

if it still doesn't work, run `taps` and see if it generates an error.  Mine was complaining that sqlite3 wasn't installed.  I installed the sqlite3 gem, and it worked

```
gem install sqlite3
```

And no, i'm not using sqlite3 anywhere in my application. Your error could be caused by some other dependency too.

If you're still having trouble uninstall both heroku and taps, and then reinstall

```
gem uninstall heroku
gem uninstall taps
gem install heroku
gem install taps
```

Comment: I had same prob, after re-installing Heroku toolbelt and taps - gem install sqlite3 made the diff for me, and I'm not using it in my app either

Comment: same issue. not using sqlite3 but installing it allowed me to run heroku db:pull

Answer (score 4):

Besides updating `taps` you should also updated `heroku`

```
gem update taps
gem update heroku
```

Then check to see if you have more than one version:

```
which -a gem
gem list
```

If that returns more than one version for `taps` or `heroku` you should remove the older ones:

gem uninstall taps
   gem uninstall heroku

You should also make sure that `rvm` is installed and working.

If you type `$ rvm` in your console you should get some output. If you do not then you need to install rvm again [here](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).

Then with `rvm list` you can see the different ruby versions. See what ruby version you are using with `ruby -v`. If it is below `1.9.2` try installing a new ruby version.